# How to find element using the value attribute with Selenium and XPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

In selenium I used the following XPATH to find all elements which have the word `ok`:

```
//button[(((@value='ok')) or ((@value='Ok')) or ((@value='OK')))]
```

What if I want to find all buttons which start with the word ok? As an example `OK1` is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all elements which have the word **ok** you can modify as follows:

```
//button[@value='ok' or @value='Ok' or @value='OK']
```

and to find all elements which starts with the word **ok** you can use:

```
//button[starts-with(@value, 'ok') or starts-with(@value, 'Ok') or starts-with(@value, 'OK')]
```

Comment: This is exact match :) plus I want them to start with ok

Comment: @john Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks I will test and accept very soon, just 2 side question, 1) I have noticed that some people use value and some use text, what's the difference? 2) Isn't there a way to do non-case sensitive search (instead of ok, OK, Ok, oK..)

Comment: You'd use `starts-with(@value, 'ok')` when the element is `<button class="classname" value="ok">`. You'd use `starts-with(., 'ok')` when the element is `<button class="classname" value="abc">okJohn</button>`

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks! but what about when I want to check exact match for: `<button class="classname" value="IGNORE ME">ok</button>`? do you do: `//button[.='ok' or .='Ok' or .='OK']`

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I will really appreciate if you answer my last question :) because what you wrote before confused me a little and I don't think it makes sense to write `.=`

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in details within the Selenium Chat Room.

Comment: Do you have a link? I can't find any

Comment: I'm sorry, check my profile page you's get the link.